Can the Windows installer (msi) read a current service's settings to keep them when updating the service?
Is it possible, in installer (msi) code, to read a service's current settings (primarily the Start value, but ideally also all the *FailureActionType values) so when it installs an update those settings will be retained rather than being set to our defaults that we use on a fresh install?
For example, the current code is simply doing this:
<util:User Id="MyServiceUser" Name="[SERVICEUSER]" CreateUser="no" LogonAsService="yes" RemoveOnUninstall="no"/>

<ServiceInstall Id="MyServiceInstall"
        Name="MyService"
        DisplayName="My Amazing Service"
        Type="ownProcess"
        Start="auto"
        ErrorControl="normal"
        Description="Performs amazing feats of computation."
        Account="[SERVICEUSER]"
        Password="[SERVICEUSERPASSWORD]">
        <util:ServiceConfig FirstFailureActionType="restart"
                SecondFailureActionType="restart"
                ThirdFailureActionType="restart"
                ResetPeriodInDays="0"
                RestartServiceDelayInSeconds="60"/>
</ServiceInstall>

But I'd like to, at minimum, retain the previous installations value of "Start", and ideally also retain the util:ServiceConfig values.
